# As3 instances from imported swf not recognized

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have made something like a level in flash editor. made some classes inside the editor that inherited from the classes in my project. next I export my swf to later be loaded by my main code.

the thing is that once I have the swf loaded I try doing some traces to check if the instances are the correct class.

```
trace(map.getChildAt(i)+" D "+(map.getChildAt(i) as PointerImage));
```

witch outputs this: [object PointerBall] D null.
PointerBall(from flash) inherites from PointerImage(from my main code).
now if I trace this

```
trace((new PointerBall())+" Y "+(new PointerBall() is PointerImage));
```

witch outputs this: [object PointerBall] Y true

so the problem is **only** with instances imported from the swf.

Comment: This is something related to `ApplicationDomain` being different in loaded SWF and its parent. I am aware of domain difference causing problems, but I don't know how to get proper classes out of the loaded SWF.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I tried it. Assuming your referenced .swf is in the same application domain as the parent. The key is to have the classes that you're referencing be in a specific package. Classes that aren't in packages are in their own namespace, in both the loaded .swf and the parent. So `PointerImage` in your loaded .swf is not the same `PointerImage` that exists in your parent. It all has to do with namespace.

Just move these classes into a package folder named game and rename the package and you should be set.

```
package game{ 
    import game.PointerImage
    public class PointerBall extends PointerImage{
        //Class code
    }
}
```

This is what I'm working with:

```
function onLoad(evt:Event):void{
    var c:MovieClip = evt.target.content as MovieClip;

    addChild(c);

    var t:BigTest = c.getChildAt(0) as BigTest;
    trace(t);  //[object LitteTest]
}
```

Comment: when you say move these classes do you refer to the clases that have no package from the exported swf?

Comment: Yes. I mean put those classes without a package into a package. Using the default package is in fact discouraged and you should always be organizing into packages. To put a class in a package, create a directory in your source path with the name of the package you're going to use. We'll create a folder called 'test' and put our class files there. Then, in the class right at the first line, specify the name of the package **this must always match the class' directory** so in this case it would be `package test{ `

Comment: I tried it and It did not work. here is what I did: 1. I changed the class to export from the object in my swf's library. before it said CharBall, after it said Default.CharBall. I compiled and the trace output was Null (was trying to cast the instance as PointerImage).

Comment: 2. next I made a folder named "Default" and made a .as file for "charBall" that inherited from "PointerImage". yet the symbol in my flash library extended from MovieClip since "PointerImage" was already defined. tried it again and it did not work.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use a LoaderContext and set the domain you want to use for either overriding the current class definitions or overriding the loaded swf ones:

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(); 
context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain; 
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
var ldr:Loader = new Loader(); 
ldr.load(urlRequest, context);
```

Working with class inheritance is ok but easier is working with Interface.

Comment: does this work for a local project? because when I tried it I got error #2142: local SWF files cannot use the LoaderContext.securityDomain property.

Comment: I don't understand the answer which is completely wrong. Voted down!